# MySQL - auto incremento compartilhado entre tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, auto-incremento

É possível fazer com que o valor do auto incremento de duas tabelas sejam compartilhados?

Exemplo:

```
Tabela 1
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | campo | criado_em |
| 1  |   a   |   00:00   |
| 2  |   b   |   01:00   |
| 5  |   c   |   04:00   |
+----+-------+-----------+

Tabela 2
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | campo | criado_em |
| 3  |   a   |   02:00   |
| 4  |   b   |   03:00   |
| 6  |   c   |   05:00   |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Não faz sentido isso que você quer fazer. Quer nos explicar qual o problema raiz para sugerirmos soluções?

Comment: Estou fazendo manutenção em um sistema legado. Atualmente eles vendem um Produto A,no qual as informações do pedido são salvas na tabela Pedido A. O ID dessa tabela é enviado para o gateway de pagamento e la esse ID é usado para identificar o pagamento. Agora o cliente quer vender um Produto B,porém não da para salvar as informações na tabela Pedido A,pois ela foi criada especificamente para o Produto A. Então eu pensei em criar uma tabela Pedido B, porém o ID dos registros não podem ser iguais ao ID da tabela Pedido A, por isso pensei em "compartilhar" o auto incremento entre as duas tabelas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te indico a usar uma tabela de vínculo e colocar o `AUTO_INCREMENT` nessa tabela com chave estrangeira para as outras duas. Em cada uma das tabelas principais você criaria uma `TRIGGER` que preencheria a tabela de vínculo no momento da inserção. Depois é só selecionar os dados da forma que descrevi na `query` abaixo:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tabela1 (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  campo VARCHAR(3)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trg_i_tabela1
AFTER INSERT ON tabela1
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO vinculo(id_tabela1) VALUES(NEW.id);

CREATE TABLE tabela2 (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  campo VARCHAR(3)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trg_i_tabela2
AFTER INSERT ON tabela2
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO vinculo(id_tabela2) VALUES(NEW.id);

CREATE TABLE vinculo (
  id         INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_tabela1 INTEGER,
  id_tabela2 INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY fk_vinculo_tabela1(id_tabela1) REFERENCES tabela1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY fk_vinculo_tabela2(id_tabela2) REFERENCES tabela2(id)
);

INSERT INTO tabela1(campo) VALUES('a1');
INSERT INTO tabela1(campo) VALUES('b1');
INSERT INTO tabela2(campo) VALUES('a2');
INSERT INTO tabela2(campo) VALUES('b2');
INSERT INTO tabela1(campo) VALUES('c1');
INSERT INTO tabela2(campo) VALUES('c2');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT v.id,
       COALESCE(t1.campo, t2.campo) AS campo
  FROM vinculo v
  LEFT JOIN tabela1 t1 ON t1.id = v.id_tabela1
  LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2 ON t2.id = v.id_tabela2
 ORDER BY v.id;
```

---

**Resultado**

```
| id  | campo |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | a1    |
| 2   | b1    |
| 3   | a2    |
| 4   | b2    |
| 5   | c1    |
| 6   | c2    |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kRjuCGPoo3JQcYzhZjZw9s/0).

Comment: Muito bem, isso resolve o problema. No caso eu mandaria para o gateway o ID da tabela vínculo

Comment: @GustavoPrimo exatamente, essa é a ideia. Tem um outro jeito de fazer, mas não é `Thread Safe` então eu faria desse jeito aí mesmo

Answer (score 0):

No my sql não sei, você pode tentar criar uma sequence, não sei se funcionaria, no Oracle eu criaria uma sequence, só que na hora de dar insert tu vai ter que dar um `nome_da_sequence.nextval`

```
 create sequence idcodcli

increment by 1

start with 10

maxvalue 999

nocycle;
```

Select :

```
select sequence_name,increment_by,max_value, last_number
           from user_sequences;
```

Comment: Por mais que você tenha uma boa intenção com a sua resposta, isso não responde a pergunta